# Understanding font shape codes, e.g. `TU/tahoma(0)/b/it' or `TU/pag/m/n'

Tags: fonts

I sometimes get error messages with these font shape codes, but I don't know what they mean, nor did I find any information about it.
Clearly, `b` stands for `bold` and `it`for `italic`. But what does `m` and `n` or the `TU`in the beginning stand for? How are the codes structured? It seems like, the font name is at the second place, followed by the font features.

Also, I'm interested in how to specify font features when selecting fonts with `fontspec` (build in and by `.TTF` file). But that might be a topic for another thread.

I'd appreciate a source where this is explained. Unfortunately, I couldn't find something by myself.
Since I ask regarding a basic understanding, I don't post a MWE or any error messages. I try to figure out how fonts work in general by myself first.

Comment: `TU` is the encoding. This is used for unicode when the engine is LuaTeX or XeTeX. If you were using LaTeX or pdfTeX, you'd get `OT1` by default or some other encoding if customised. `Tahoma(0)` is the font name. In this case, it's probably created on-the-fly and `(0)` is presumably an index, in case another font is defined later with the same base name. The third slot is the series: bold, medium, bold extended or whatever. This encompasses both weight and width, a fact which has led to a good deal of trouble. The final slot is shape, which has also led to a complications.

Comment: What you're seeing here is basically the interface `fontspec` creates to enable you to use arbitrary fonts, even though they aren't set up as traditional TeX fonts and don't have the support files LaTeX expects. It's essentially a function of the fact that the use of unicode fonts is an extension of the original facilities LaTeX 2e provides for font handling, rather than font support being constructed from the start with such fonts in mind.

Comment: None of this has much to do with specifying features with `fontspec`. By design, its functions hide the gory details behind a custom interface. See the `fontspec` manual for details (`texdoc fontspec`). It may be reasonable not to provide an MWE for the first question, though it would be helpful to have one which produces the messages you are asking about. But it is not reasonable to ask how to specify features with `fontspec` without providing some code explaining what you've tried and what problem you're encountering. That *certainly* needs an MWE.

Comment: `n` is upright.

Answer (score 1):

Fonts have five attributes:

1. encoding
2. font family
3. font series
4. font shape
5. font size

These attributes are encoded in the internal font name itself, which is the very clever idea that made font management effective when NFSS (new font selection scheme) was integrated in the LaTeX kernel in the mid 90's (kudos to Frank Mittelbach and Rainer Schöpf).

The encoding attribute tells LaTeX how to interpret some commands such as `\'` or `\texttrademark`. For instance, with the OT1 encoding, `\'` is (basically) interpreted as “add an acute accent on top of the next character”; in T1 it becomes “look for the next character and, if a precomposite character with the acute accent, then use it, otherwise place an acute accent over it”. With TU it's similar to T1, but instead of placing an acute accent, TeX (in a Unicode aware engine) is told to put a combining acute after the character, if no precomposed exists.

Commands such as `\texttrademark` are treated a bit differently: in OT1 or T1, LaTeX is instructed to choose the character from the corresponding TS1 encoded font (keeping the other attributes, perhaps doing some substitutions if the font with those attributes is unavailable); in TU it just points to the corresponding Unicode slot.

The next attribute is the font family, which is a basically arbitrary string that LaTeX uses together with the encoding to define a font family which can be set up “manually” in the document or by reading a *font description* file.

When `fontspec` is used, the font family is set up on the fly and a family name is built using the font name and a number, unless a font family name is explicitly set.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}

\newfontfamily{\oldstandard}{Old Standard}

\newfontfamily{\futura}{Futura}[NFSSFamily=fut]

\begin{document}

\expandafter\string\the\font

\oldstandard

\expandafter\string\the\font

\futura

\expandafter\string\the\font

\end{document}
```

With `\the\font` we access the current internal font name and `\string` will print it.

[image]

Some warning or informational messages omit the size, which is irrelevant when they're emitted. For instance, in some cases substitutions are made and, if the substitution is not defined as “silent”, an informational message will appear. As an example, with

```
{\fontshape{y}\selectfont x}
```

you'd get

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/LibertinusSerif(0)/m/y' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/LibertinusSerif(0)/m/n' instead on input line 14.
```

because no `y` shape is defined. You see that the size attribute is omitted, because irrelevant.

The series and shape attributes are encoded with a somewhat arbitrary string, but there are some standard names:

1. series `m` means “medium”, the standard one
2. series `b` means “boldface” (in some cases you see `bx`)

Font description files may define several others. For instance, the T1 encoded Source Sans Pro font defines

`regular` `bold` `black` `semibold` `extralight` `light`

and also defines aliases

`m` `b` `eb` `sb` `el` `l`

Other font description files might use `k` for black. Mileage can vary a lot.

The shape attribute is similar. The standard shapes are

`n` `it` `sl` `sc`

but font description files may add to them, maybe `scit` or `scsl` for italic/slanted small caps. The string `n` stands for “normal”, typically upright; `it` is “italics”, `sl` is “slanted” and `sc` is “small caps”.

The ones you mentioned refer to a `fontspec` defined font, because of `tahoma(0)`; for `TU/pag/m/n` I'm uncertain on how you got it, as there is no corresponding font description file. However, the string `pag` follows Karl Berry's naming convention for fonts: in the olden times file names had to be restricted to at most eight characters, in order to comply with a stupid file system which I'm sure you know the name of. The letter “p” stands for “Adobe” (the digital foundry providing the font) and “ag” refer to Avant Garde. See `texdoc fontname` for more information on the subject.

Comment: "a stupid file system which I'm sure you know the name of"  ISO_9660 CD format

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I was thinking to a different one, which the CD format had to comply with. 

Comment: I am sure that all the gurus know this, but it is not often mentioned: With `fontspec` it is possible to use non-integer font sizes. May make a difference if you are using a size-quantized font such as LMR. But in general, `fontspec` can size to 11.43pt or whatever. I do it all the time. May require first loading with an acceptable integer value, then redefining to mainfont to be the desired size.

Comment: You can use fractional sizes also in standard LaTeX, provided the font is fully scalable. Latin Modern is, for example. Also the CM fonts are, provided you load `fix-cm`.